# SSDT Disable renaming - refactor log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I use SSDT for my database. My constraint is continuous delivery. So I can't do renaming at all, it will break compatiblity with previous (running) version of the DAL.
Is there a way to set SSDT project in this way, to avoid refactor ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the refactor log in your pre build *but* you can do continuous delivery with renames you just need to make your changes in a non breaking way and phase your changes until your apps have been updated.

Have a read of this:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-delivery/non-breaking-online-database-deployments/

Ed

Comment: Wouldn't deleting the refactor log just mask the fact that a rename had happened? This could potentially be dangerous as instead of renaming a column it could drop one with data and add a new one with nulls.

Comment: So just 2 solutions, SQL procedure OR Acces every thing by view :( Is there an other solution without complicate my database ?

Comment: If you combine deleting the refactorlog with the BlockOnPossibleDataLoss= true deployment setting, this should break the build in the event of any renames.